# Generating a random sequence using Scala

Tags: scala, sequence

I need to get a random sequence of 100 values from 10^-10 to 10^10 and storing to an `Array` using Scala. I tried following but it didn't work

```
Array(scala.math.pow(10,-10).doubleValue to scala.math.pow(10,10).intValue by scala.math.pow(10,5).toLong)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to `fill()` the array with `Random` elements.

```
import scala.util.Random

val rndm = new Random(1911L)
Array.fill(100)(rndm.between(math.pow(10,-10), math.pow(10,10)))
//res0: Array[Double] = Array(6.08868427907728E9
// , 3.29548545155816E9
// , 9.52802903383275E9
// , 7.981295238889314E9
// , 1.9462480080050848E9
// . . .
```

This works because the 2nd parameter to the `fill()` method is "by-name", i.e. re-evaluated for every element.

---

**UPDATE**

Things aren't quite as clean if you don't have the `.between()` method (Scala 2.13).

```
Array.fill(100)(rndm.nextDouble())
     .map(_ * math.pow(10,10))
```

Note that this actually has a floor of `0.0` instead of the desired `0.0000000001`. It's very unlikely you'd have an entry that's too small, especially when taking only 100 samples. Still, there are steps you could take to insure that can't happen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am getting following error

Comment: error: value between is not a member of scala.util.Random

Comment: scala version  "2.11.12"